# Convergence of $(X_nY_n)$ to zero where $X_n, Y_n$ are not necessarily independent

Tags: convergence-divergence, stochastic-processes, random-variables

Let $X_n, Y_n$ be random variables s.t. $\sup_n \mathbb{V}(X_n)<\infty$ and $\lim_n \mathbb{V}(Y_n)=0$, as well as $\mathbb{E}(X_n)=\mathbb{E}(Y_n)=0$ for all $n$. Show that $(X_nY_n)_n$ converges in probability to $0$.

I wanted to use the Chebyshev inequality, but that approach would require the random variables to be independent so that the expected values could be "merged". As the random variables are not independent, I don't know how to tackle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P(|X_nY_n| >\epsilon) \leq \frac {E|X_nY_n|} {\epsilon}$. Now use Holder's inequality: $E|X_nY_n| \leq \sqrt {EX_n^{2}} \sqrt {EY_n^{2}}$.

Answer (score 3):

By Cauchy Schwarz and the fact that all variables have mean 0,

$$
\mathbb{E} |X_nY_n|\leq \sqrt{\mathbb{V} X_n}\sqrt{\mathbb{V}Y_n}\to 0,
$$
so $X_nY_n$ goes to $0$ in $L^1$. In particular, it goes to $0$ in probability.